# Simple, quick encryption for setting cookies in PHP (Symfony2)

Tags: php, symfony

I'm setting some cookie values where the values are slightly sensitive, but nothing too serious.

Basically I would like to encrypt the value, but just a very quick, basic method.

I'm thinking base64 but that seems to return a really long string.

It just needs to be really quick and simple. Quick being low processing time.

Something like this is too much: http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

I'm using Symfony2 but I don't think there's anything in there to help me (e.g. built-in cookie encryption).

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What's the use case?

Comment: base64 is not encryption. You should not be storing sensitive information in cookies, you should be encrypting it properly ([mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php), [openssl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php)) and storing it on the server side. Also, hashing is not the same as encryption, they are different mechanisms with different applications and use cases. Also, speed should not be your primary concern, in general the speed of an encryption/hashing procedure is inversely proportional to the level of security it provides. Bcrypt is artificially slower for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

The NelmioSecurityBundle can encrypt cookies. https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioSecurityBundle#encrypted-cookies

Answer (score 0):

If the data you want to store in the cookie are sensitive, you should **not** store them in cookies in the first place.

I recommend using [sessions](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/sessions.html). This way the data will not be transferred to the user but will still be accessible by your PHP scripts on the server.